# Form line-height changed when I added a select input to my form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I started building my form first by adding only textboxes for simplicity until I decide how I wanted it to look.

Later when I added a few other types of inputs, like a dropdown selector for example, the form started changing the line height at the rows where those element where located.

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------

[image]

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------

[image]

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------

Simpy styling the line height into a smaller value did not work for me because all inputs, no matter how big they look on the form report the same line-height of 26px, and changing it to a smaller value makes the label overlap with that small line below each input.

How can I fix this and have my form display as it did in the beginning?

[image]

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention that it might be a label issue, because the label for all selectors displays at the bottom.

**EDIT2:**

My code looks something like this

```
<md-input-container flex="" layout="column" ng-repeat="field in row">
      <!-- input label -->
      <label>{{field.label}}</label>
      <input name="field.field" ng-model="field.val">
</md-input-container>
<md-input-container flex="" layout="column" ng-repeat="field in row">
      <!-- input label -->
      <label>{{field.label}}</label>
      <md-select ng-model="field.val">
        <md-option ng-repeat="c in field.list" value="{{c.value}}">{{c.label}}</md-option>
      </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

**EDIT3:**

It seems that `md-select` inherits a padding of `24px 2px 26px` from `angular-material.css` at *6022* that is responsible for this. I still doubt though that in angular material everyone has to remove the default padding of a select input to make it align with all other inputs.

Comment: It must be taking some height from some css class. can you paste your html here ?

Comment: @KapilGarg just did. I will search the various css styles to see if there is something messing it up.

Comment: After deleting all other css files except from ngMaterial's the problem still persisted. this [pen](http://codepen.io/Tanooki/pen/gpgEeO)  here though is showing fine!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is simple and obvious to anyone who takes the time to carefully see the examples provided.

In any case what one must do is make sure to either not use `<label>` at all or if he does then use `<md-select-label>` for the select input.